# Create a flowable with generate function using RxJava2

Tags: java, kotlin, observable, rx-java2, backpressure

I need to create a custom Flowable with backpressure implemented. I'm trying to achieve some sort of paging. That means when downstream requests 5 items I will "ask the data source" for items 0 - 5. Then when downstream needs another 5, I'll get items 5 - 10 and emit back.

The best thing I've found so far is to use `Flowable.generate` method but I really don't understand why there is no way (as far as I know) how to get the `requested` number of items the downstream is requesting. I can use the `state` property of generator to save the index of last items requested so then I need only the number of newly requested items. The emmiter instance I got in the BiFunction `apply` is `GeneratorSubscription` which is extending from `AtomicLong`. So casting emmiter to `AtomicLong` can get me the requested number. But I know this can't be the "recommended" way.

On the other hand when you use `Flowable.create` you get the FlowableEmitter which has `long requested()` method. Using `generate` is suiting me more for my use-case, but now I'm also curious what is the "correct" way to use `Flowable.generate`.

Maybe I'm overthinking the whole thing so please point me in the right direction. :) Thank you.

This is what the actual code looks like (in Kotlin):

```
Flowable.generate(Callable { 0 }, BiFunction { start /*state*/, emitter ->
        val requested = (emitter as AtomicLong).get().toInt()  //this is bull*hit
        val end = start + requested
        //get items [start to end] -> items
        emmiter.onNext(items)
        end /*return the new state*/
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out that the `apply` function of the BiFunction is called that many times as is the request amount (n). So there's no reason to have a getter for it. It's not what I have hoped for but it is apparently how `generate` works. :)